# How to do what YouTube does with the grey boxes while loading?

Tags: javascript, youtube, lazy-loading

I've started to notice that when loading a YouTube page, before content is loaded, everything appears as grey boxes:

[image]

Want to try this out and cannot find answers. Only come across articles of people asking for help because the content didn't actually load for them, ex: [YouTube Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/PYc94lQSfKY;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/category$3Areport-a-technical-issue%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false)

Is this YouTube's way of lazy loading? **is this mainly done with `Javascript`?**

Comment: Related: [What is the name of this practice when a page loads?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/115117). This is not really recommended. It’s been described as a [“A placebo for slow internet”](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/109178).

Comment: Why the down vote though? Thought this was legit a good thing, especially for accessibility.

Comment: Your question is too broad. It’s not really clear what you need, or what kind of answers you expect.

Comment: I only have 2 question written there followed by a question mark. I would  like to know what is the best approach to do this. Thanks for the links btw, helps a bit.

Answer (score 7):

This technique is also called "skeleton screen".

Comment: I leave you two links where you can find info about how to implement it.

 [source 1](https://www.leejamesrobinson.com/blog/loading-placeholder-with-sass/) - 
 
 [source 2](https://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html)